# Too many SOQL queries: 101 - Test Class w. no queries / DML inside loops

Tags: apex, unit-test, picklist

I have a trigger which contains several Ifs, populating my record's fields with different values, depending on which picklist value has been selected.

So I need to test Inserts & Updates of records with each value. Running this Test Class succeeds.

```
@isTest
public class WE_OppUpdatesTest {

    static testMethod void testNewMRFs(){

        Profile p1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator - Wex Europe'];

        User[] userList = new User[]{};
            User u = new User();

        u.FirstName = 'Alex';
        u.LastName = 'Sherwood';
        u.Email = 'test@wexeurope.com';
        u.Username = 'astest@wexeurope.com';
        u.Alias = 'astest';
        u.ProfileId = p1.Id;
        u.TimeZoneSidKey    = 'America/Denver';
        u.LocaleSidKey      = 'en_US';
        u.EmailEncodingKey  = 'UTF-8';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        userList.add(u);

        insert userList;

        System.runas(u){

            WEID__c[] csList = new WEID__c[]{};
                WEID__c cs = New WEID__c();
            cs.Name = 'CP Virtual Prepaid MC';
            cs.WEOppId__c = '012700000005qif';

            csList.add(cs);

            insert csList;

            Target__c[] targetList = new Target__c[]{};
                Target__c t = new Target__c();

            t.Name = 'Jun Test';
            t.OwnerId = u.Id;
            t.Salesperson__c = u.Id;
            t.Team__c = 'Virtual Sales EU';
            t.Year_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015,12,31);
            t.Target__c = 100000;
            t.Month_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015,06,30);
            targetList.add(t);

            Target__c t1 = new Target__c();
            t1.Name = 'Jul Test';
            t1.OwnerId = u.Id;
            t1.Salesperson__c = u.Id;
            t1.Team__c = 'Virtual Sales EU';
            t1.Year_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015,12,31);
            t1.Target__c = 100000;
            t1.Month_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015,07,30);
            targetList.add(t1);

            Target__c t2 = new Target__c();
            t2.Name = 'Jul 16 Test';
            t2.OwnerId = u.Id;
            t2.Salesperson__c = u.Id;
            t2.Team__c = 'Virtual Sales EU';
            t2.Year_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2016,12,31);
            t2.Target__c = 100000;
            t2.Month_End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2016,07,30);
            targetList.add(t2);

            insert targetList;

            List<Opportunity> opportunitys = new List<Opportunity>();

            for (Integer i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

                Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
                o.name = 'Test Opp' + i;
                o.RecordTypeId = '012700000005qif';
                o.OwnerId = u.Id;

                o.StageName = '1) Suspect';
                o.CloseDate = date.newInstance(2015,06,15);
                o.Ramp_Profile__c = 'Standard';

                o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c = 0;
                o.Annual_transaction_volume__c = 1000;
                o.Credit_Limit__c = 100.00;
                o.Date_Credit_Limit_Approved__c = date.newInstance(1901, 01, 01);
                o.Payment_Terms_Days__c = 5;
                o.Billing_Cycle__c = 'Daily';
                o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c = 100.00;
                o.Average_transaction_Value_POS__c = 1.00;

                opportunitys.add(o);
            }
            insert opportunitys;

            //UPDATES
            for(Opportunity upOppsDate : opportunitys){
                upOppsDate.CloseDate = date.newInstance(2016,07,15);
                upOppsDate.Ramp_Profile__c = 'Immediate';
                upOppsDate.Implementation_Revenue__c = null;
                upOppsDate.FSR_End_Date__c = null;
                upOppsDate.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = null;
            }
            update opportunitys;

            for(Opportunity upOppsRMP : opportunitys){
                upOppsRMP.Ramp_Profile__c = 'Medium';
                upOppsRMP.Implementation_Revenue__c = null;
                upOppsRMP.FSR_End_Date__c = null;
                upOppsRMP.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = null;
            }
            update opportunitys;

            for(Opportunity upOppsRMP : opportunitys){
                upOppsRMP.Ramp_Profile__c = 'Extended';
                upOppsRMP.Implementation_Revenue__c = null;
                upOppsRMP.FSR_End_Date__c = null;
                upOppsRMP.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = null;
            }
            update opportunitys;

        }
    }
}
```

But as soon as I add an extra DML statement to my Test Class (either Insert or Update) for example -

```
List<Opportunity> immOpportunitys = new List<Opportunity>();

            for (Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

                Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
                o.name = 'Test Opp' + i;
                o.RecordTypeId = '012700000005qif';
                o.OwnerId = u.Id;
                o.Ramp_Profile__c = 'Immediate';
                o.StageName = '1) Suspect';
                o.CloseDate = date.newInstance(2015,06,15);
                o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c = 0;
                o.Annual_transaction_volume__c = 1000;
                o.Credit_Limit__c = 100.00;
                o.Date_Credit_Limit_Approved__c = date.newInstance(1901, 01, 01);
                o.Payment_Terms_Days__c = 5;
                o.Billing_Cycle__c = 'Daily';
                //cover Revenue Values Required validation rule
                o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c = 100.00;
                o.Average_transaction_Value_POS__c = 1.00;

                immOpportunitys.add(o);
            }
            insert immOpportunitys;
```

It causes the error

> System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

So it looks like each time I Insert / Update a new set of records, any resulting SOQL queries from other code are added to a governor limit which is being totaled for this class, when in reality only one batch of records could be Inserted / Updated at once. Changing the number of records in the lists, which are being changed, doesn't seem to make any difference.

Surely I should be able to Insert / Update multiple lists of records in the same Test Class, with separate governor limits for each, to test the different picklist values?

Note - the trigger which I'm testing doesn't contain any SOQL queries so to keep the question short, I haven't posted it.
My debug log size is too large to filter in the Developer Console, due to a (hopefully) unrelated issue but there's no obvious signs of an SOQL query in a loop, when I search it.

Comment: Might not help in this scenario but don't forget to use test.starttest() and test.stoptest() : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: @Girbot thanks, I've tried this but the SOQL query for the Profile's not causing the issue in this case.

Comment: Test.StartTest() resets ALL Limits. 
Put debug logging level to NONE, apart from apex code put that to Error.
Then add;
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Error,  ' <<<<<<<< ' + Limits.getSOQL() );

List of all governor limits and the call to debug them
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm

Failing debug use an assert and just move it along, Error will be in a forloop

Comment: Tim that's useful for future reference, the error's not being caused by a particular For loop, it's being caused when multiple For loops are Inserted / Updated. Obviously I can only use Start & Stop test once - and my understanding is that you'd using this with a single DML statement so again, since there's multiple DML statements, I don't think that this solves my issue.

Comment: @TimChadwick but Test.StartTest does help now that I'm [retrieving values from my `@testSetup` method](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82367/combining-testsetup-runas-in-a-test-class), thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your limit exception is probably that you're trying to do to many operations in one transaction.

You need to know that all governor limits are counted against one transaction. Transaction is not one class execution - it is the whole stack of calls.

Example:

- You insert opportunity // Transaction begins
- beforeInsert trigger is executed (let's say it has 1 SOQL query inside - limit of soql for transaction equals 1 right now)
- afterInsert trigger is executed (let's say it has 2 SQOL and update of related record - Account)
- account beforeInsert is executed...
- account afterInsert
- End of transaction (success if no error, and governor limits are not exceeded)

So if you have your test class - in one method you're making multiple inserts - it's all counted as one transaction.

Best practice for test class development is to separate it to multiple methods - each testing one thing. This way each test method is executed separately and have separate governor limits. Also good practice is to include method with @testSetup method when you will insert all records required for other test methods.

```
@isTest
public class WE_OppUpdatesTest {

   @testSetup
   static void dataSetup() {
      ...
      insert user;
   }

   static void additionalDataSetup() {
      User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'yourname' LIMIT 1];
      System.runAs(u) {
         ... insert all additional records
      }
   }

   static testMethod void test_something() {
      additionalDataSetup();
      ...
   }

   static testMethod void test_somethingElse() {
      additionalDataSetup();
      ...
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Maciek for the more complete explanation, I'm testing this now and it looks like the separate test methods are the key. Also, the `@testSetup` suggestion makes the Class much simpler. I'll get back to you on this soon.

Comment: In order to create both the User & the other records (Custom Setting, Targets etc.) in my test class, I have to use Run As to separate the two DML Operations. This seems to be causing an issue when I use `@testSetup`. The compiler's telling me that it can't access values from inside the runas loop (which is inside the `@testSetup' loop). Will I have to recreate the runas records for each test method? I'm happy to post this as a separate question btw.

Comment: Usually what I do, I insert user in @testSetup method, and in each test method I call something like `User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'YourName' LIMIT 1]; System.runAs(u) { ...`

Comment: But you don't combine the user creation with the creation of the other records using runas in the @testSetup method? I'm not sure that what you've suggested would allow me to create both sets of records without causing a Mixed DML Operation error.

Comment: Ah, yes you're probably right, now I remember having such issue. So I looked into some of examples and what I did was actually: in `testSetup` I only inserted user. Then I had another static void `additionalDataSetup` which inserted all required records with the user context using `User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'YourName' LIMIT 1]; System.runAs(u) { ...`. Then in each testMethod i called `additionalDataSetup()` first. This inserted all required objects and didn't have issue of mixed DML. I added it to above answer code snippet.

Comment: Thanks so I'd just posted this as a separate question [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82367/combining-testsetup-runas-in-a-test-class). I'm sure it would be useful to make that solution easier to find as an answer so if you'd like to post it, I won't delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should check Opportunity triggers. Also, instead of testing all cases in a single test method, try to break them in different test methods.

You should check all SOQLs in Opportunity triggers and also all triggers which run during the update of an Opportunity.

Try to decrease following record counts:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 50; i++)
```

Start from one or two iterations only.

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    ......
}
```

Otherwise, you may encounter issues caused by SOQL queries in for loops OR recursive triggers.

Comment: Thanks for this but as I mentioned, I've checked my Opportunity triggers & the problems not that they include SOQL queries, it's that for each DML statement in my test, their queries are being added to a total for the class. Also, reducing the number of records being Inserted / Updated doesn't make have any effect. It looks like there aren't any SOQL in loops or recursive triggers causing an issue. I thought that creating multiple Test Classes was inefficient and will slow down my deployment? It doesn't make sense that Salesforce would make that necessary - but maybe it is..

Comment: @AlexS Do not create multiple classes, create multiple test methods in same class breaking the use cases.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying so just add another `static testMethod void testNewMRFspt2(){`?